# Change path name to admin page in Zimbra

Tags: domain, zimbra, centos6.4

I have installed Zimbra on CentOS 6.4. Now I would like to change the path to the admin page from:

```
https://mail.domain.com:7071/zimbraAdmin/
```

to `https://mail.domain.com/admin/`. So can I do this, and how to do?

Comment: Port 443 is used by https [mailbox] - web mail client over ssl  in zimbra, you can't use the same port for two different application.

Comment: I mean replacing the first link by the the second one, not using two link in the same time

Comment: @FedericoSierra well, you can, as long as you adjust jetty.xml - jetty is already serving both WebApps so it's just matter of configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zimbra (ZCS) is using **Jetty** as application server with configuration file generated from template and variables. You can either:

a) adjust `zimbraAdminPort` and `zimbraAdminURL`

```
# su - zimbra

$ zmprov
prov> getConfig zimbraMailSSLPort
zimbraMailSSLPort: 443
prov> getConfig zimbraAdminPort
zimbraAdminPort: 7071
prov> getConfig zimbraAdminURL
zimbraAdminURL: /zimbraAdmin

prov> modifyConfig zimbraMailSSLPort 4443
prov> modifyConfig zimbraAdminPort 443
prov> modifyConfig zimbraAdminURL /admin

$ zmmailboxdctl restart
```

b) or adjust `/opt/zimbra/jetty/etc/*` with custom ports, path, filters etc. according [jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/) to suit your needs